# I have 3 CSS buttons but the other one has <br />

Tags: html, reactjs, css, flexbox

I am having a problem on making the three css buttons have the same size (using padding) and making it vertically aligned because the 2nd button has a "< br />" which makes it not equal to the other two. Also, I was told to use flex box. I want the buttons to aligned with the same size but can't do.

here's the html:

```css
.flex.container.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: relative;
}

.child {
  background-color: rgb(242, 242, 242);
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 25px;
  margin: 4px;
  color: rgb(75, 75, 75);
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="article container">
  <div class="flex container parent">
    <div class="child">ARTICLES</div>
    <div class="child">
      CASE STUDIES /<br /> WHITEPAPERS
    </div>
    <div class="child">NEWS/EVENTS</div>
  </div>
```

Thanks for the help everyone really appreciate it!! It's now working the way I want!

Comment: set min-height to the button class and check.

Comment: I tried doing that but the text in two button without br would no longer be in the middle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `align-items:center` from the parent and put it on the children (after giving them `display:flex`).

```css
.flex.container.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: relative;
}

.child {
  background-color: rgb(242, 242, 242);
  padding: 25px;
  margin: 4px;
  color: rgb(75, 75, 75);
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="article container">
  <div class="flex container parent">
    <div class="child">ARTICLES</div>
    <div class="child">
      CASE STUDIES /<br /> WHITEPAPERS
    </div>
    <div class="child">NEWS/EVENTS</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: For some reason in "run code snippet" it looked like your solutions worked. But in my local it did not.

Comment: Have you checked the code in your local version...note that it's NOT the same as edited into your original post. For instance `.flex .container .parent` was in your original code but should be `.flex.container.parent` (no spaces) also I used `class` not `className`.

Comment: Am using reactJS so when I changed the className to class it gave me an "unknown property" error

Comment: I'm just pointing out the differences...but the spaces/no spaces thing would have been the big one.

Comment: i changed the classname of the flex parent to a 1 word, and it worked!

Comment: Thank you for the help I really appreciate it! :D

Answer (score -1):

You should simply assign a height to the `.child`. This way you can control that all elements will have the same height. Eventually you can use `max-height`.

```css
.flex.container.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: relative;
}

.child {
  background-color: rgb(242, 242, 242);
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 25px;
  margin: 4px;
  color: rgb(75, 75, 75);
  text-align: center;
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="article container">
  <div class="flex container parent">
    <div class="child">ARTICLES</div>
    <div class="child">
      CASE STUDIES /<br /> WHITEPAPERS
    </div>
    <div class="child">NEWS/EVENTS</div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score -2):

```css
.parent {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: stretch;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: relative;
}

.tab-selections {
    background-color: rgb(242, 242, 242);
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 25px 100px;
    margin: 4px;
    color: rgb(75, 75, 75);
    text-align: center;
}

.child {
  margin:0 10px;
  background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="article container">
  <div class="flex container parent">
    <div class="child">ARTICLES</div>
    <div class="child">
      CASE STUDIES /<br />
      WHITEPAPERS
    </div>
    <div class="child">NEWS/EVENTS</div>
</div>
```